# How can I export my project to an AAB file?

Tags: android, export, apk, godot

I dont know what the problem is but when I try to export my project to an AAB does not work and this message appears, I wonder if you can help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbbek.png)

PS. Sorry for my bad english

I already installed the JDK17, configure all in Godot, intall the templates, etc.

I expect that I can export my game

Comment: Please don't post errors and stack trades as image (with bad contrast). Just edit your question and include it as text formatted as code.

Comment: I think the important part is `Could not update C:\Users\Badir\Documents\pruebaexportar\android\build\.gradle\7.4.2\fileChanges\last-build.bin`. reboot your computer and delete/rename that file and retry.